# A word for a tendency to overreact

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm analyzing a story in which there is a character who has unnecessarily extreme reactions to any situation that she's in — for example, she falls in love with a man (who she can't even speak to because of a language barrier) practically at first sight, and when he eventually dumps her, she is so distraught and so convinced that she will never be happy again that she (content warning) commits suicide. I am looking for a single noun that describes this as a character trait because I am trying to write a sentence like this (in which "foobarity" is a stand-in for the real word that I'm looking for):

> She has essentially four character traits: compassion, naïveté, foobarity, and discontent with the norms of her society.

I could simply write "tendency to overreact/catastrophize," but this does not flow as well as a single word would, and I feel like there is a single word. That phrase as a Google query doesn't yield any useful results, and "volatility," "irascibility," etc. feel not quite right because they carry a connotation of specifically having a temper. Am I simply imagining that there's a word for what I'm trying to describe?

Comment: She sounds like an airhead suffering from *flightiness*.

Comment: And impetuous. . .

Comment: It depends if you want something stereotypically feminine and weak (like *flightiness*) or something more positive (being quick to react).

Comment: I would go with volatility. I don't think it implies anger, necessarily.

Comment: @Xanne — The noun *impetuousness* doesn’t exactly roll off the tongue or out of the brain.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "[Impetuosity](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/impetuosity)"?

Answer (score 0):

You could call the person **dramatic,** [defined by MW as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dramatic)

> having or showing a tendency to behave or react in an exaggerated way